# How to insert name from session into paypal form correctly?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm building an automatic PayPal checkout for my game's website. The user can buy virtual stuff with PayPal but I need to post his account name to PayPal's IPN to be able to run the processing script correctly.

So, how can I paste into his account name from session to the paypal button correctly?

My PayPal button includes this line:

```
<input value='accountname' name='custom' type='hidden'>
```

and I can recall the user name in an another page like this:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION["user_name"]; ?>
```

How can I mix this two thing together well? I need to paste user_name into the value.

Comment: start the session and assign it a value

Comment: the session is started but I don't know how to assign the value inside an input stuff correctly

Comment: assign a session array to the POST array and its value